# How do I merge 2 dataframes based on or condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two df, ABC and LOP.
ABC: has a lot of columns and there are three key columns called [A], [B], [C]
LOP: has a lot of column and there are one key columns called [L]

```
ABC_data = [['A001', 'B001','C001','xxx','nnn'], ['A002', 'B002','C002','yyy','mmm'], ['A003', 'B003','C003','zzz','ooo']] 
ABC = pd.DataFrame(ABC_data, columns = ['A', 'B','C','Other_1','Other_2']) 
print(ABC)

 A     B     C Other_1 Other_2
0  A001  B001  C001     xxx     nnn
1  A002  B002  C002     yyy     mmm
2  A003  B003  C003     zzz     ooo
```

[ABC_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93QWL.png)

```
LOP_data = [['A002','sth1'], ['B004','sth2'], ['C002','sth3'], ['C003','sth4']] 
LOP = pd.DataFrame(LOP_data, columns = ['L', 'other_info']) 
print(LOP)

  L other_info
0  A002       sth1
1  B004       sth2
2  C002       sth3
3  C003       sth4
```

[LOP _data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYbwb.png)

**What I want**: I want to do **left join**, ABC as the left df, LOP as the right df.
based on if the value in [L] equals to [A] **or** [B] **or** [C].

Notice: [L] can only equal to one of [A],[B],[C], which means it will not equal to [A] and [B] at the same time

If it equals, then left join the value in all LOP columns
If there is no [L] value match [A] or [B] or [C], then will be null

**the result should looks like this：**

```
 A     B     C Other_1 Other_2     L L_other_info
0  A001  B001  C001     xxx     nnn  None         None
1  A002  B002  C002     yyy     mmm  A002         sth1
2  A002  B002  C002     yyy     mmm  C002         sth3
3  A003  B003  C003     zzz     ooo  C003         sth4
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sarh.png)

**What I tried**

1. I tried merge function but it only can do AND, but I have to do OR
2. I tried triple the ABC table, and 1st copy let [B] and [C] to be NULL, the 2nd copy let [A] and [C] to be NULL, and 3rd copy let [A] and [B] to be Null. Then merge them with LOP seperately and concat the 3 df. But I have trouble to remove the row because if I remove all [L] are NULL value rows, it will remove the case [there is no L match ABC], but I want to keep these NULL and remove the duplicate in 3 df, so I fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `.melt()` before merging:

```
df_m = (
   ABC.reset_index()
      .melt(id_vars=['index', 'Other_1', 'Other_2'], value_name='L')
      .merge(LOP, on='L', how='left') 
      .dropna()
      .set_index('index')
)
```

```
      Other_1 Other_2 variable     L other_info
index
1         yyy     mmm        A  A002       sth1
1         yyy     mmm        C  C002       sth3
2         zzz     ooo        C  C003       sth4
```

You can then merge that back using the indexes:

```
ABC.merge(
    df_m[['L', 'other_info']], 
    left_index=True, 
    right_index=True, 
    how='left'
)
```

```
      A     B     C Other_1 Other_2     L other_info
0  A001  B001  C001     xxx     nnn   NaN        NaN
1  A002  B002  C002     yyy     mmm  A002       sth1
1  A002  B002  C002     yyy     mmm  C002       sth3
2  A003  B003  C003     zzz     ooo  C003       sth4
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! 
It works in this sample df but i find I did not state clearly about the exact df. So I have ~100 columns in ABC and ~100 columns in LOP, how should I change the id_vars part? I feel I can't list all the ~100 columns. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Can you get that info from the dataframe? eg. `ABC.columns.difference(['A', 'B', 'C'])` should give you all the column names except `'A', 'B', 'C'`